# How to split string into a dictionary

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have this string

```
string sx="(colorIndex=3)(font.family=Helvetica)(font.bold=1)";
```

and am splitting it with

```
string [] ss=sx.Split(new char[] { '(', ')' },
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Instead of that, how could I split the result into a `Dictionary<string,string>`? The
resulting dictionary should look like:

```
Key          Value
colorIndex   3
font.family  Helvetica
font.bold    1
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There may be more efficient ways, but this should work:

```
string sx = "(colorIndex=3)(font.family=Helvicta)(font.bold=1)";

var items = sx.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { '=' }));

Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    dict.Add(item[0], item[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 85):

It can be done using LINQ *ToDictionary()* extension method:

```
string s1 = "(colorIndex=3)(font.family=Helvicta)(font.bold=1)";
string[] t = s1.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =
                      t.ToDictionary(s => s.Split('=')[0], s => s.Split('=')[1]);
```

**EDIT**: The same result can be achieved without splitting twice:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dictionary =
           t.Select(item => item.Split('=')).ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1]);
```

Comment: Didn't even know that Split function can take string array as argument. Neat.

Comment: Is there any way of avoiding calling `s.Split()` twice?

Comment: Sure, by calling t.Select(item => item.Split('=')).ToDictionary(s => s[0], s => s[1]); Similar to @erikkallen & @Luke answers.

Comment: @Snickbrack, Since I totally forgot about this answer :) I've edited and now the answer contains the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

[Randal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22483/randal-schwartz) [Schwartz](http://www.stonehenge.com/merlyn/) has a [rule of thumb](http://perl.plover.com/flagbook/yak/Chi/slide066.html): use split when you know what you want to throw away or regular expressions when you know what you want to keep.

You know what you want to keep:

```
string sx="(colorIndex=3)(font.family=Helvetica)(font.bold=1)";

Regex pattern = new Regex(@"\((?<name>.+?)=(?<value>.+?)\)");

var d = new Dictionary<string,string>();
foreach (Match m in pattern.Matches(sx))
  d.Add(m.Groups["name"].Value, m.Groups["value"].Value);
```

With a little effort, you can do it with [`ToDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary.aspx):

```
var d = Enumerable.ToDictionary(
  Enumerable.Cast<Match>(pattern.Matches(sx)),
  m => m.Groups["name"].Value,
  m => m.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Not sure whether this looks nicer:

```
var d = Enumerable.Cast<Match>(pattern.Matches(sx)).
  ToDictionary(m => m.Groups["name"].Value,
               m => m.Groups["value"].Value);
```

Answer (score 13):

```
string sx = "(colorIndex=3)(font.family=Helvetica)(font.bold=1)";

var dict = sx.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(x => x.Split('='))
             .ToDictionary(x => x[0], y => y[1]);
```

Comment: Hmmm, I just noticed that this is functionally the same as erikkallen's answer, but using extension method syntax rather than query syntax.

Comment: @Luke, to me your answer is more readable but that might just be formatting.

Comment: @Tuzo: I generally prefer the extension method syntax too, but it's all down to personal taste I think.

Comment: Luke, why should the dict be a anonymous type why cant it be a dictionay
Thanks - tony

Comment: @unknown: `dict` *is* a `Dictionary<string, string>`. In this case the `var` keyword has nothing to do with anonymous types, it just means that the compiler determines that `dict` is actually a dictionary and saves me some typing! The generated code is *exactly* the same as if I'd declared it with `Dictionary<string, string> dict` etc. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx

Answer (score 9):

```
var dict = (from x in s1.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            select new { s = x.Split('=') }).ToDictionary(x => x[0], x => x[1]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Often used for http query splitting.

```
Usage: Dictionary<string, string> dict = stringToDictionary("userid=abc&password=xyz&retain=false");

public static Dictionary<string, string> stringToDictionary(string line, char stringSplit = '&', char keyValueSplit = '=')
{
    return line.Split(new[] { stringSplit }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(s => s.Split(new[] { keyValueSplit })).ToDictionary(x => x[0], y => y[1]); ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
string sx = "(colorIndex=3)(font.family=Helvetica)(font.bold=1)";

var keyValuePairs = sx.Split(new[] { '(', ')' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(v => v.Split('='))
            .ToDictionary(v => v.First(), v => v.Last());
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with regular expressions:

```
string sx = "(colorIndex=3)(font.family=Helvetica)(font.bold=1)";

Dictionary<string,string> dic = new Dictionary<string,string>();

Regex re = new Regex(@"\(([^=]+)=([^=]+)\)");

foreach(Match m in re.Matches(sx))
{
    dic.Add(m.Groups[1].Value, m.Groups[2].Value);
}

// extract values, to prove correctness of function
foreach(var s in dic)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", s.Key, s.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just putting this here for reference...

For ASP.net, if you want to parse a string from the client side into a dictionary this is handy...

Create a JSON string on the client side either like this:

```
var args = "{'A':'1','B':'2','C':'" + varForC + "'}";
```

or like this:

```
var args = JSON.stringify(new { 'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':varForC});
```

or even like this:

```
var obj = {};
obj.A = 1;
obj.B = 2;
obj.C = varForC;
var args = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

pass it to the server...

then parse it on the server side like this:

```
 JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 Dictionary<String, String> dict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<String, String>>(args);
```

JavaScriptSerializer requires System.Web.Script.Serialization.