# How do I turn a text file into a Dictionary<string,string>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, file-io

I am creating a hangman game in visual studios for class. I have this text file:

```
LOVE,An intense feeling of deep affection
PROCRASTINATION,The action of delaying or postponing something
ANNOYED,Slightly irritated
HAPPY,A feeling or showing pleasure and contentment
EDUCATION,The process of imparting or acquiring knowledge.
```

There are 10 lines of that. I need to turn those text lines into a `Dictionary<string,string>`

My problem is that I don't know how to read text from a text file, loop through each line, and assign different parts of the line to a dictionary. For example, I need "ANNOYED" to be a dictionary key and "Slightly irritated" to be the value pair to that key.

Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Hangman
{
    //Create fields
    private string _directory = "../../../output/";
    private string _file = "Dictionary.txt";
    private Random _random = new Random();
    private Dictionary<string, string> _words;
    
    

    public Hangman()
    {
        _words = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string path = _directory + _file;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    //Split up each word and the definiton into a dictionary
                    string words = sr.ReadLine();
                    string[] definitions = words.Split(',');
                    _words.Add(definitions[0], definitions[1]);
```

Is anyone able to help me out? When I Console.WriteLine this out, it gives me a never ending loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split string into a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852200/how-to-split-string-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: where is the rest of the code?

Comment: What if your dictionary value contains a comma? If you only want the first comma you should use `IndexOf(',')` not `Split(',')`.

Answer (score 1):

One problem in your code is that you're reading a source line into the variable `line`:

```
while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
```

And then reading another within the `while` into the variable `words` which is then split into an array:

```
string words = sr.ReadLine();
```

I don't know why the loop would be never-ending; in fact, your code should error after the `while` reads the last line and you try to split a null `words`.

Anyway, this works:

```
...
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // Split up each word and the definition into a dictionary
        string[] definitions = line.Split(',');
        _words.Add(definitions[0], definitions[1]);
    }
}
...
```

**EDIT**

Referencing @Jawad's answer, here's a simplified version using `File.ReadAllLines` and `Linq`:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
Dictionary<string, string> _words = lines.ToDictionary(key => key.Split(',')[0], val => val.Split(',')[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of reading one line at a time, you can read in the entire file at once. Use `ToDictionary()` method to convert your list of strings into a dictionary that you are looking for.

From Linq, use `Select` statement to produce the array of two elements (using `Split`) for each line, then convert these to Dictionary using `ToDictionary` method.

```
// using System.IO;
// using System.Linq;

string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"../../inputFile.txt");
var _words = lines.Select(x => x.Split(','))
                  .ToDictionary(x => x.First(), y => y.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault())

// OR, Take the string before comma as key, and anything after that as value (including other commas in value)
var _words = lines.ToDictionary(x => x.Split(',').FirstOrDefault(), 
                                y => string.Join(",", y.Split(',').Skip(1)));
```

You can print the dictionary using the Newtonsoft.Json Serializer,

```
Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_words, Formatting.Indented));

// Prints:
{
  "LOVE": "An intense feeling of deep affection",
  "PROCRASTINATION": "The action of delaying or postponing something",
  "ANNOYED": "Slightly irritated",
  "HAPPY": "A feeling or showing pleasure and contentment",
  "EDUCATION": "The process of imparting or acquiring knowledge."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on [Dictionary<>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0) for how to use it, and also how to access [string arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_arrays.asp).

The answer is simple.

```
_words.Add(definitions[0],definitions[1]);
```

Comment: But it gives me a never ending loop

Comment: Yikes!  Well, for one, I don't think you need `string words = sr.ReadLine()` at all.  Remove that line and then change the next to `string[] definitions = line.Split(',');`  It's hard to see the root-cause without you posting the whole while loop (not sure what else you're doing).

Comment: That was all I had in the while loop

Answer (score 0):

After you have split the line:

```
string line = sr.ReadLine();
string[] lineParts = words.Split(",".ToCharArray());
```

You can assign to Dictionary:

```
_words[lineParts[0]] = lineParts[1];
```