# C# Something messed up with this function spilt()

Tags: c#

I'm stack with this function **spilt()**

As you know via this function  **spilt()** you can get any string between two strings, words, etc..

I read a lot about this function [https://learn.microsoft.com/ spilt() Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split)

And I read many topics on Stackoverflow and Codeproject, watched many videos on Youtube

I lost more than 3 hours to solve the matter but IN VAIN!!!

I made an example, here is it

```
        String mainstring = "when pigs fly";
        MessageBox.Show(mainstring); // Output: when pigs fly
        mainstring = mainstring.Split(new[] { "when", "fly" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
        MessageBox.Show(mainstring); // Output: pigs
```

Everything was ok and the output is correct (I'm talking about the right way to use this function)

But the matter when I tried to use it again with a different project it didn't get the exact string and the output was different

Here is my code which I'm stuck on

```
                             string mainstring = @"{CODE_1:Enter Your Key!}
{CODE_2:vip}
{CODE_3:vip}
{CODE_4:Select Server}
{CODE_5:https://[TS]/A_API/GetAccess.php}
{CODE_6:[K]}
{CODE_7:[IP]}
{CODE_8:[PP]}
{CODE_9:[Version]}";

                    CODE_5 = mainstring.Split(new[] { "{CODE_5:", "}" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];

                    MessageBox.Show(CODE_5);
```

The output wasn't `https://[TS]/A_API/GetAccess.php`
the output was  `{CODE_3:vip`

Comment: Split does not return "the part between both separators" (there may be more than two separators, even). Instead it returns the parts that are delimited by *any* of the separators. Try your original code with `mainstring = "when pigs fly then a fly pigs out"`. In your second text there are a lot of `}` to split on - which did happen

Comment: This might be interesting for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1852200/how-to-split-string-into-a-dictionary

Comment: This does indeed seem much more like "not understanding the purpose of the method" than anything else. I really don't think Split is what you want here - at least not like that. I'd split the string on line breaks to get each line, then parse each line to a key/value pair, then find the key you want.

Comment: Seems more a task for a regular expression like `Regex.Match(input, @"(?<={CODE_5:)[^}]*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Split` to split your main string on multiple different values, you could probably still retrieve the value you want, but using a different index.

Instead of trying to split your main string with both strings at once like your current code:

```
mainstring.Split(new[] { "{CODE_5:", "}" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
```

try splitting it up, into two actions:

```
mainstring.Split(new string[] { "{CODE_5:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(new string[] { "}" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

and see what you get.

This should first give you:

`mainstring.Split(new string[] { "{CODE_5:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]` =

> https://[TS]/A_API/GetAccess.php}
> {CODE_6:[K]}
> {CODE_7:[IP]}
> {CODE_8:[PP]}
> {CODE_9:[Version]}

which can then be split on `"}"`, which would give us:

`mainstring.Split(new string[] { "{CODE_5:" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1].Split(new string[] { "}" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0]` =

> https://[TS]/A_API/GetAccess.php

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Edited to fix, the `Split` implementation needs to be the `string` array overload.